# How to use css to find some elements of the same level？

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How to use css to find some elements of the same level？

```html
<p class=h1>a</p>
<p class=h2>a1</p>
<p class=h3>a11</p>
<p class=h3>a12</p>
<p class=h2>a2</p>
<p class='h1 current'>b</p>
<p class=h2>b1</p>
<p class=h3>b11</p>
<p class=h3>b12</p>
<p class=h2>b2</p>
<p class=h1>c</p>
<p class=h2>c1</p>
<p class=h2>c2</p>
```

I want to use css to get the following elements, how should I find it?

I tried to find it like this `.current~p:not(.current~.h1~p)` , but it failed.

```html
<p class=h2>b1</p>
<p class=h3>b11</p>
<p class=h3>b12</p>
<p class=h2>b2</p>
```

Comment: You mean you want to address b1, b11, b12, and b2 bases on text content of 'b'? That's not possible with CSS

Comment: The only CSS way to dynamically find the first 4 after the `.current` is using `.current + p,
.current + p + p,
.current + p + p + p,
.current + p + p + p + p { color: red; }` ... and if this is not what you mean, but rather a random amount of siblings, you'll need script

Comment: The best you can do with CSS only is `.current ~ p:not(.h1)`, but that also selects c1 and c2, which I reckon you don't want. You'd need to use JS for this (if I understand your problem correctly) https://jsfiddle.net/nr4k9fmL/

Comment: For a proper answer, clarify the rule for how those elements should be selected.

Comment: I want to find based on .current, and the number of elements is not fixed.

Comment: Based on _what_ from `.current`? ... all but the one's not having a certain content ... or a certain class ... or ?

Answer (score 0):

By what I understood of your question you want to address all the `.h2` and `.h3` paragraphs that are following siblings of a `.h1.current` paragraph, but you want any of those who follow an intermittening `.h1` that is not a `.current` to be not addressed by the rules.

Alas that is not possible in the current layer of CSS, because the `:not()` pseudo class can only take simple CSS selectors and not complex ones.

But you can try to address the following siblings and revert the style to the initial value like this.

```css
.h1 {
  margin-left: 10px;
  text-decoration: underline double orange;
}

.h2 {
  margin-left: 30px;
  /* *1* */
  text-decoration: underline solid green;
}

.h3 {
  margin-left: 50px;
  /* *2* */
  text-decoration: underline overline dashed blue;
}

/* This gets all the followers to .h1.current which are .h2 or .h3 */
.h1.current~.h2,
.h1.current~.h3 {
 /* *3* */
  text-decoration: line-through double red;
}

/* this gets all .h2 followers of .h1 which itself follows .h1.current */
.h1.current~.h1~.h2 {
  /* overwrite *3* by copying *1* properties */
  text-decoration: underline solid green;
}
/* this gets all .h3 followers of .h1 which itself follows .h1.current */
.h1.current~.h1~.h3 {
  /* overwrite *3* by copying *2* properties */
  text-decoration: underline overline dashed blue;
}
```

```html
<p class=h1>a (not this)</p>
<p class=h2>a1 (not this)</p>
<p class=h3>a11 (not this)</p>
<p class=h3>a12 (not this)</p>
<p class=h2>a2 (not this)</p>
<p class='h1 current'>b (this is current)</p>
<p class=h2>b1 (this)</p>
<p class=h3>b11 (this)</p>
<p class=h3>b12 (this)</p>
<p class=h2>b2 (this)</p>
<p class=h1>c (breaks the above chain)</p>
<p class=h2>c1 (not this)</p>
<p class=h3>c21 (not this)</p>
<p class=h3>c22 (not this)</p>
<p class=h2>c2 (not this)</p>
```

This rule should work with CSS4
`.h1.current ~ p:is(.h2, .h3):not(.h1.current ~ .h1:not(.current) ~ p)`
but we cannot use it right now. jQuery however does support complex selectors in the `:not` pseudo class (but not the `:is()`), so here is the same example with jQuery support

`.h1.current ~ p:not(.h1):not(.h1.current ~ .h1:not(.current) ~ p)`

```js
jQuery('.h1.current ~ p.h2:not(.h1.current ~ .h1:not(.current) ~ p), .h1.current ~ p.h3:not(.h1.current ~ .h1:not(.current) ~ p)').css('backgroundColor', 'magenta')
```

```css
.h1 {
  margin-left: 10px;
  text-decoration: underline double orange;
}

.h2 {
  margin-left: 30px;
  /* *1* */
  text-decoration: underline solid green;
}

.h3 {
  margin-left: 50px;
  /* *2* */
  text-decoration: underline overline dashed blue;
}

/* This gets all the followers to .h1.current which are .h2 or .h3 */
.h1.current~.h2,
.h1.current~.h3 {
 /* *3* */
  text-decoration: line-through double red;
}

/* this gets all .h2 followers of .h1 which itself follows .h1.current */
.h1.current~.h1~.h2 {
  /* overwrite *3* by copying *1* properties */
  text-decoration: underline solid green;
}
/* this gets all .h3 followers of .h1 which itself follows .h1.current */
.h1.current~.h1~.h3 {
  /* overwrite *3* by copying *2* properties */
  text-decoration: underline overline dashed blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class=h1>a (not this)</p>
<p class=h2>a1 (not this)</p>
<p class=h3>a11 (not this)</p>
<p class=h3>a12 (not this)</p>
<p class=h2>a2 (not this)</p>
<p class='h1 current'>b (this is current)</p>
<p class=h2>b1 (this)</p>
<p class=h3>b11 (this)</p>
<p class=h3>b12 (this)</p>
<p class=h2>b2 (this)</p>
<p class=h1>c (breaks the above chain)</p>
<p class=h2>c1 (not this)</p>
<p class=h3>c21 (not this)</p>
<p class=h3>c22 (not this)</p>
<p class=h2>c2 (not this)</p>
```

Comment: Even if this answer works, it is more difficult to understand than necessary. Instead, to allow for the OP to focus on _how_ it works, keep it simple and change/reset e.g. the text color.

Comment: @LGSon Feel free to improve my answer

Comment: In general, I don't rewrite that much code in someone's answer. If you want the credit, you do the work. And FYI, I noticed your down vote, and it wasn't me. If you edit and simplify it, you'll get my upvote. Let me know if you did.

Answer (score -1):

Why not CSS `:nth-child()` selector?

```css
p:nth-child(nth)
```

Then if you want to use it to select multiple element, just

```css
p:nth-child(1),
p:nth-child(2),
p:nth-child(3)
```

Comment: nth-child can select only one element at a time. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16371722/select-multiple-child-in-css

Comment: You can't combine `nth-child` with the in this case `.current` class. `nth-child` always start at the first child, no matter class, and here it is unknown.