# HTML responsive navigation show first and last item always

Tags: html, css

I have following code for responsive navigation bar. Right now all the menu times hide for small screen except Home button.

I need to keep Search menu also for the small screen. How can I do this in below code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    
    .topnav {
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #333;
    }
    
    .topnav a {
      float: left;
      display: block;
      color: #f2f2f2;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 17px;
    }
    
    .topnav a:hover {
      background-color: #ddd;
      color: black;
    }
    
    .topnav a.active {
      background-color: #4CAF50;
      color: white;
    }
    
    .topnav .icon {
      display: none;
    }
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      .topnav a:not(:nth-child(1)) {display: none;}
      .topnav a.icon {
        float: right;
        display: block;
      }
    }
    
    
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
      .topnav.responsive .icon {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
      }
      .topnav.responsive a {
        float: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
      }
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
      <a >Home</a>
      <a >News</a>
      <a >Contact</a>
      <a>About</a>
      <a ><i class="fa fa-search"></i>Search</a>
    
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
      </a>
      
    </div>
    
    
    <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
      if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
      } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
      }
    }
    </script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

I tried by adding `.topnav a:not(:nth-child(5)) {display: none;}` with the existing css but not working. I already found select multiple child [select multiple child in css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16371722/select-multiple-child-in-css), but no idea how to apply here .

Comment: There are better ways of doing what you are trying to do. You don't need to use `float`, just use flexbox and some javascript to achieve the desired layout. [Demo](https://jsbin.com/fecipededi/1/edit?html,output)

Comment: Thanks I will refer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead..

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}
.topnav a:nth-child(2){display:none;}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a{display: none;}
  .topnav a:first-child,.topnav a:nth-child(2){display: block;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}



@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a:nth-child(6){display:none;}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a >Home</a>
  <a><i class="fa fa-search"></i>Search</a>
  <a >News</a>
  <a >Contact</a>
  <a>About</a>
  <a><i class="fa fa-search"></i>Search</a>

  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Still some issue the search menu appearing on side menu also when I open with menubar.

Comment: Are you need to show search bar fixed with Home menu when below @600 responsive ??

Comment: Yes the serch bar and home button both need to keep, rest should appear on side menu

Comment: Check now @CodeDezk